# Allow row only if referred row has specific value in field

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose that some kind of entity (in one table) can have a status of *OK* or *Error*. 
For those entities that have a status of *OK* there should also be some data (in another table), but when the status is *Error* there should be no data.

A row should thus only be allowed to exist in the latter table if the row it refers to in the first table has status set to *OK*.

What's the recommended way to force this constraint in a database?

Comment: I'm guessing you insert data in these 2 tables via PHP ? Why don't you only insert data in the second table, if the value you inserted in the first table = 'OK' ?

Comment: use trigger on second table and check for existence of OK/Error record in first table.

Comment: @kristof_w That's of course something I will do. But if someone changes things directly in the database, inconsistencies might occur. That's why foreign keys and triggers exist.

Comment: @Romil Thanks. That's one way to do it.